# Excel Vlookup Multiple columns

Tags: excel

Worksheet

```
Emp#  Name  Phone1  Phone2  Phone3
34    Joe   4538
678   Fred           7690    1234
54    June  7190             6645
3467  Ted            6702
```

I would like to search by phone number and return `Emp#` and `Name`.  I tried using a helper column with concatenated phone numbers, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Emp` use:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(I2=$C$1:$E$5),ROW(A1:A3)^0),0))
```

for `Name` use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,MMULT(--(I2=$C$1:$E$5),ROW(A1:A3)^0),0))
```

both are array formulas - confirm with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

Change function `ROW(A1:A3)^0` according to column count in search range, i.e. in range `C1:E5` is three cols so I use `ROW(A1:A3)`, for five cols use `ROW(A1:A5)` and so on.

[image]